# How can i apply feature reduction methods in Weka?

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification

1) How can i apply feature reduction methods like LSI etc in weka for text classification?

2) Do applying feature reduction methods like LSI etc can improve the accuracy of classification ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Take a look at [FilteredClassifier](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/meta/FilteredClassifier.html) class or at [AttributeSelectedClassifier](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Performing+attribute+selection). With FilteredClassifier you can use such features reduction method as Principal Component Analysis (PCA). Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PY20auk5F_E) how to filter your dataset using PCA, so that you could try different classifiers on reduced dataset.
2. It can help, but there is no guarantee about that. If you remove redundant features, or transform features in some way (like SVM or PCA do) classification task can become simpler. Anyway big number of features usually lead to [curse of dimensionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) and attribute selection is a way to avoid it.

Comment: @KashifKhan If I answered your question please mark it as accepted and optionally vote up for it.

Comment: yes i was doing it but some problem (electricity load shedding) prevent me from doing this. Perhaps you may be able to answer another query, I am performing text classification via weka. I apply feature selection via IG on the data set (20NewsGroup) and find out a surprising classification accuracy (91.1%). After this i re-apply feature selection along with feature reduction (PCA) and this time i expected a better accuracy even by a small margin but i disappoints me by reducing accuracy to 76%. Is feature reduction in text classification improve accuracy of decrease it ?

Comment: @KashifKhan It actually depends on the features that you are using. It's impossible to say in advance if feature reduction will increase or decrease the accuracy. I assume to gain accuracy from feature reduction there should be redundant features, or features should have some relations among them, etc. If neither is true, you can actually remove useful features and decrease amount of information available for a classifier of your choice.

Comment: @KashifKhan I would recommend to search for some advices on using feature reductions (maybe in scientific papers). You can also post a question on http://metaoptimize.com/qa/ about your specific problem if your are stuck.